# How to join array in fetch request with different variable types in React?

Tags: reactjs, fetch-api

I'm working on a React component that requests data via fetch and gets as a response a JSON object that consists of values that are either strings or arrays of strings.

I want to render each of the keys and values in a list. If the value is an array I want to convert it to a string delimited by semicolons. However, whenever I try to convert the array to a string via the .join() method during the mapping process, the mapped elements never render. If I remove the .join() method from the mapping the constant renders fine.

Why can't I use the .join() method during the process of mapping data returned from fetch? Or am I doing something else wrong? I'm not seeing any error in the console that would point to a problem in the syntax.

This also seems to apply to mapping within the mapping function (as opposed to using join).

```
class Record extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      data: []
    }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://127.0.0.1:9200/_index/_doc/1')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(json => this.setState({data: json._source}))
  }
  render() {
    const data = this.state.data
    const record = Object.keys(data).map((f, i) => {
      return <li key={i}>{f} : {typeof data[f] === 'object' ? data[f].join('; ') : data[f]}</li>
    })
    return (
      <ul>
        {record}
      </ul>
    )
  }
}
```

EDIT: an example of a data response is:

{"foo": "string", "bar": ["baz", "fred"], "anotherfield": "anotherstring"}

which should ideally display as:
foo: string
bar: baz; fred
anotherfield: anotherstring

Comment: Can you include a small example of what `data` might look like? Also is `data` an array or object?

Comment: Since we don't know what `data` contains, we can't help much. I tested with `data=[['foo', 'bar'], 'baz']` and got expected results so we need to know how your `data` looks.

Comment: updated: data response is an object. Example is in the original post body.

Comment: Nit: you should use `Array.isArray` to check if something is an array, not `typeof === 'object'`

Comment: @MatthewHerbst it looks like that change fixed it. I think what happened is that some of the values were null, thus returning true for typeof === 'object', but because null values can't be joined, it was breaking the mapping. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that some of the values returned from the data were null, which returns 'true' for typeof === 'object'. Therefore, I needed to use Array.isArray(data[f]) instead.